# Do avro and parquet formatted data have to be written within a hadoop infrastructure?

Tags: file, hadoop, avro, parquet, file-format

I've been researching the pros and cons of using avro, parquet, and other data sources for a project. If I am receiving input data from other groups of people who do not operate using Hadoop, will they be able to provide this input data in avro/parquet format? My reading so far on these formats has only been within the sphere of the Hadoop infrastructure, so I am wondering how difficult it would be for folks who just use Oracle/SQL to provide data in this format.

Comment: Typically, such datasets don't accumulate on a single machine. Therefore, Hadoop w/ a query layer (or Athena / Bigquery) are used for actual analytics

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use these formats without Hadoop, but the ease of doing so depends on the language binding.

For example, reading/writing Parquet files on standalone machines may be very cumbersome with the Java language binding (which is even called `parquet-mr` where mr stands for MapReduce), as it builds heavily on Hadoop classes. These are typically provided on the classpath of a Hadoop cluster, but are less readily available on standalone machines.

(While `parquet-mr` is mainly a Java library, it also contains some tools that users may want to run on their local machine. To work around this issue, the `parquet-tools` module of `parquet-mr` contains a compilation profile called `local` that packages Hadoop dependencies alongside the compiled tool. However, this only applies to `parquet-tools` and you have to compile it yourself to make a local build.)

The python language binding, on the other hand, is very easy to set up and works fine on standalone machines as well. You can either use the high-level [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet) interface or the actual implementations [pyarrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html)/[fastparquet](https://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) directly.